# Why isn't my mobile site able to send AJAX requests?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

The first action available in my mobile app is a login. The form calls the javascript:

```
$.post('http://www.website.com/m/users/login', ...
```

I use a catch-all ajax error:

```
$(document).ajaxError(ajaxError);
function ajaxError() {
    hideLoader();
    enableForm( $('form:visible') );
    alert('Uh oh! An error occurred. Please make sure you have an internet connection and try again.');
}
```

And that alert is all I get when I try to log in.

Even though it isn't cross domain (the mobile site is at `mobile.website.com`), I have tried:

```
$.support.cors = true;
$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
```

But it still isn't working. At this point I'm out of ideas, so I thought I'd see if anyone knew of any other possible roadblocks for JQM ajax requests.

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you AJAX'ing www.website.com FROM www.website.com ?

Comment: No, from `mobile.website.com`.

Comment: Then you need to ask MR www.website.com to add your website into his Allow headers to allow cross domain communications.. Otherwise forget about it..OR JSONP like mentioned..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try review technique called JSONP this way you can perform cross-site invocation

Answer (score 1):

You are performing a cross-domain request,`www.website.com` is not the same domain as `mobile.website.com`. You either need to expose the methods on the mobile.website.com domain, make www.website.com support CORS, or provide some kind of proxy between the two.

Comment: Wouldn't my `$.support.cors = true; $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;` be doing that? If not, what do you mean by "expose the methods"?

Comment: By expose the methods, I mean make them available from the mobile.website.com domain if possible. The `$.support` structure is nothing more than information about the current browser, changing it's values doesn't change whether or not the server you are requesting from is returning the correct headers for a CORS request. I don't know what `$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true` does.

Answer (score 0):

Using [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) will also let you do Cross domain AJAX calls

Build your URL query using [YQL Console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/) and use the YQL query directly in your code and you will get the response reliably